# How to test NGXS in angular component?

Tags: angular, ngxs

I am new to `NGXS` and  while testing I am getting error in all test cases.
I am getting data from store:
`app.component.ts`

```
    somedata: Idetail
    this.someData = this.store.selectSnapshot(State.details).
    this.data = this.someData.DATA;
```

But I am getting error on every single test case:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'DATA' of null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to mock the store to use it inside Tests.

E.g.:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent]
      imports: [NgxsModule.forRoot([])] // import real module without state
   });

   const store:Store = TestBed.get(Store);
   spyOn(store, 'select').and.returnValue(of(null)); // be sure to mock the implementation here
   spyOn(store, 'selectSnapshot').and.returnValue(null); // same here
}));
```

Comment: I tried this but got error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngInjectableDef' of undefined

Comment: worked for service but getting same error in component

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be an odd topic but hopefully, I can give away a few tips on unit testing NGXS with Angular component:

> Imports `NgxsModule.forRoot([StateName1, StateName2, ...])`, and then add every constructor injection from StateName1 (and StateName2, ...) under `TestBed.configureTestingModule` *providers* (ensure you already had proper mocks for each injection) and this is really **important**.

Here is my example:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent]
      imports: [NgxsModule.forRoot([NAME_OF_YOUR_TESTING_STATE])]
   });
```

and

```
await TestBed.compileComponents().then(async () => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NAME_OF_YOUR_TESTING_COMPONENT);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();

      store = TestBed.get(Store);
      store.reset(NAME_OF_YOUR_TESTING_STATE);
      actions$ = TestBed.get(Actions);
});
```

> You should define *store* and *actions$* object beforehand

```
let store: Store;
let actions$: Observable<any>;
```

After all, you could test the following if action ButtonChange is dispatched and isButtonChanged is updated:

```
public changeButton(value: string): void {
       this.store.dispatch(new ButtonChange(value));
       this.isButtonChanged = true;
}
```

I can simply achieve it with:

```
it('should segmentButtonChanged', () => {
        let actionDispatched = false;
        zip(actions$.pipe(ofActionDispatched(ChangeButton))).subscribe(() => (actionDispatched = true));

        const mockedString = 'hello there';
        component.changeButton(mockedString);

        expect(actionDispatched).toBeTruthy();
        expect(component.isButtonChanged).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: is there a way to avoid importing the services even mock services? because i have a lot of services that needs to be mocked.

Comment: @rosiejaneenomar unfortunately, I have no solution so far but importing all service

Answer (score 1):

If you can provide more of your code and/or a stackblitz, then I think you will find more help.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get data from the store into the component for your unit test, then do the following:

- In TestBed.configureTesdtingModule add to your imports NgxsModule.forRoot([StateName])
- Make sure that the component has the correct Selector setup to get the data in
- In your unit test case get the Store instance: `const store: Store = TestBed.get(Store);`
- Dispatch store action from the test case `store.dispatch(new AddToDo(toDo));`
- Check the response on the component

For more info go to the docs https://www.ngxs.io/recipes/unit-testing I found the really helpful when was starting with NGXS, which was 4 weeks ago :)